# Sencha Touch 2: How to get HTML as well as input values from a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering how to get the HTML of a panel AS WELL AS the input values from a panel?  I can get the HTML like:

```
myPanel.getInnerHtmlElement().dom.innerHTML
```

But that only return me the HTML.  For example if I have some HTML like below in Panel:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

And then enter a name in the text box, it should come back something like:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">
```

instead I am getting back:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

Does anyone know how to get the HTML back with the input values as well?  Thanks.

Comment: you can get value of text field directly and you've got innerHTML of panel too. Create new text field element and just add `value=something_you_got` to it and there's your element.

Comment: @phazorRise I have no control over the html I am getting, The only modifications would be from an outside user putting values on inputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified the value attribute on the DOM whenever the value was changed:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function () {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

And then got the HTML when needed via:

```
myPanel.getInnerHtmlElement().dom.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that panel is a `Ext.form.Panel` then you can use this to get the values of all user inputs:

```
myPanel.getValues();
```

If it's a regular old panel that happens to have form fields (which maybe you should rethink), then you can do this:

```
var values = {};
Ext.each(myPanel.query('textfield'), function() {
  values[this.getName()] = this.getValue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.get(html_element_id).setHtml(your_custom_html);` this is for setting as like you can use `getHtml` for getting the value